# Rickshaw Stacked Multi-graph

Tags: coffeescript, rickshaw, dashing

I am working with this [multi-graph Dashing widget](https://gist.github.com/swilcox/6695849).  It works correctly, but it uses only two data series and I want to add one more.  I have modified the .coffee file to

```
    class Dashing.Mgraph extends Dashing.Widget
 
  @accessor 'current', ->
    return @get('displayedValue') if @get('displayedValue')
    points = @get('points')
    if points
      points[0][points[0].length - 1].y + ' / ' + points[1][points[1].length - 1].y ' / ' + points[2][points[2].length - 1].y
 
  ready: ->
    container = $(@node).parent()
    # Gross hacks. Let's fix this.
    width = (Dashing.widget_base_dimensions[0] * container.data("sizex")) + Dashing.widget_margins[0] * 2 * (container.data("sizex") - 1)
    height = (Dashing.widget_base_dimensions[1] * container.data("sizey"))
    @graph = new Rickshaw.Graph(
      element: @node
      width: width
      height: height
      renderer: 'area'
      stroke: false
      series: [
        {
        color: "#fff",
        data: [{x:0, y:0}]
        },
        {
            color: "#222",
            data: [{x:0, y:0}]
        },
        {
            color: "#333",
            data: [{x:0, y:0}]
        }
      ]
    )
 
    @graph.series[0].data = @get('points') if @get('points')
 
    x_axis = new Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.Time(graph: @graph)
    y_axis = new Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.Y(graph: @graph, tickFormat: Rickshaw.Fixtures.Number.formatKMBT)
    @graph.renderer.unstack = true
    @graph.render()
 
  onData: (data) ->
    if @graph
      @graph.series[0].data = data.points[0]
      @graph.series[1].data = data.points[1]
      @graph.series[2].data = data.points[2]
      @graph.render()
```

However, when I run dashing, nothing it displayed (not even my other widgets).  It is just a blank screen.  Can anyone tell me what is going on here?

EDIT:

I have isolated the problem more.  It seems that everything works until I add the third data series in `series:` It seems to be this that causes it to not work.

Comment: Not sure if my question is unclear, or nobody knows the answer...

Comment: Just wondering if you happened to post the same question to the owner of the multi graph on git hub.

Comment: Not the owner, but I posted it on dashing's github.  No answer yet.  I suppose I should post it there as well though, thanks.

Comment: I need to get this running too. I will let you know if I fix it. But, folks in Dashing community are speaking high of the rickshaw graph widget. You may want to try that aswell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, try using rickshawgraph widget https://gist.github.com/jwalton/6614023

Here is my .rb

```
points1 = []
points2 = []
points3 = []
(1..10).each do |i|
  points1 << { x: i, y: 10 }
  points2 << { x: i, y: 10 }
  points3 << { x: i, y: 10 }
end
last_x = points1.last[:x]

SCHEDULER.every '2s' do
  points1.shift
  points2.shift
  points3.shift
  last_x += 1
  points1 << { x: last_x, y: rand(50) }
  points2 << { x: last_x, y: rand(10) }
  points3 << { x: last_x, y: rand(100) }

  series = [
        {
          name: "set1",
          data: points1
        },
        {
          name: "set2",
          data: points2
        },
        {
          name: "set3",
          data: points3
        }
       ]
   send_event('convergence', series: series)
end
```

Here is my .erb

```
% content_for :title do %>My super sweet dashboard<% end %>
<div class="gridster">
<ul>
    <li data-row="1" data-col="1" data-sizex="2" data-sizey="1">
    <div data-id="convergence" data-view="Rickshawgraph" data-title="Convergence" data-unstack="true" data-stroke="true" data-default-alpha="0.5" data-color-scheme="compliment" data-legend="true" data-summary-method="last"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```